# How to check if website uses cookies or not using Curl command?

Tags: curl, cookies

I want to know if a server is using cookies or not using Curl command.
I used this command `curl -k  -c - "domain name"`
but i got response as

`Access denied# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.`

How do i verify it?

Answer (score 0):

by using `grep` to search the the headers for cookies and using `wc` to give a TL;DR,

```
curl 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804909/how-to-check-if-website-uses-cookies-or-not-using-curl-command' -o /dev/null --dump-header - 2>&1 | grep -i "set-cookie" | wc -l
```

prints >=1 if the page is using cookies, and (almost certainly) prints 0 otherwise. it works by looking for the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header which is used to set cookies.